# Return from first column of a categorized view when using readers fields

Tags: xpages, repeater, lotus-notes

I have a Notes Categorized view of documents. Some of these documents have a Reader Field set. I'm building a 'view' of these documents in a series of nested Repeat Control. The first repeat is bound to a viewScope variable, called vsCat1 and I set vsCat1 in the AfterPageLoad event by opening the view and getColumnValue(0) which returns a list of the categorized data. The issue is that there is a category in the list that a particular user does not have Reader access to. So nothing displays in the repeat control where the document information is displayed, which is right. Now I could iterate through all the documents to determine if the person can in fact read it but that would add way more overhead than I want to add. I would settle for a display of something like "*** Access Restricted ***" or ?? 
In the repeat that displays the data I tried checking to see if veData == null but it never gets there.
The result is not fatal and if there is one or more unrestricted documents in the category the user would never know. But if all documents in the category are restricted the user sees the category but can not do anything and it looks strange. Plus depending on the category structure it might yield information that would reveal sensitive information. Say the category is "Purchase of Company XYZ" it could be pretty bad.
This is a broader issue than XPages but how do others handle this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check 'Don't show empty categories' in the view property, on the Style tab ?

Have a look at this : https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1LO58079

Comment: If I switch to Test User1 and open the view in question there are 4 documents displayed which is correct and the categories are only the ones that Test User1 can read. In my control that displays the repeat I open the view and getColumnValues(0) which returns all of the categories in the view not just the ones that Test User1 has reader access to. I do the getColumnValues in SSJS so I guess it is not using the current users right. The reader rights seem to only be enforced when we actually try reading a document. I don't want to have to cycle through all the documents, too much overhead.

Comment: Perhaps can you try to get all categories with a viewNavigator instead of a getColumnValue

Comment: something like that :
'code'
var lstCat:java.util.HashMap=new java.util.HashMap();
var nav:NotesViewNavigator = database.getView("By category").createViewNav();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
while (entry != null && !entry.isTotal()) {
 lstCat.put(entry.getColumnValues().firstElement().toString(), entry.getChildCount().toFixed();
 var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextSibling(entry);
 entry.recycle();
 entry = tmpentry;
}
'code'

Comment: with a bit of modification to the way that I'm doing things the using the NotesViewNavigator returns the Categories based on the Readers field. Thanks